# How to get an ERC20 token listed in etherscan.io

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, etherscan

In [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io), under the TOKEN drop down menu, there is a list of tokens,
and it is indicated that they all are ERC20 standard tokens

1) How do they get listed? Do we have to register a new ERC20 token somewhere or are they automatically recognized by etherscan?

2) If I add an extra function to an ERC20 standard contract, for example:

> function mint(uint256 _amountToMint) {...}

Is the new contract still an ERC20 contract ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Etherscan's FAQ page](https://etherscanio.freshdesk.com/support/solutions) answers your first question in the "Token Tracker Listings" section.  Here is what it says:

> Any compatible ERC20 tokens on the Ethereum blockchain can be publicly
>   and transparently tracked via https://etherscan.io/token-search
>
> In addition to the above ERC20 token tracker, we also have a selected
>   list of tokens at https://etherscan.io/tokens. The decision to list
>   these tokens here are based on the following criteria, but not limited
>   to :
>
> - Token Popularity and Demand (important)
> - Supported by a large exchange (i.e Poloniex, Kraken, Coinbase)
> - Has a unique proposition/utility
> - Visible website, about us, team page, company mailing address, official support channels like reddit, twitter, slack, facebook.
> - Fully ERC20 compliant (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20)
> - Is NOT a ponzi, pyramid, mlm or other similiar schemes
>
> You may request for a token to be added on the
>   https://etherscan.io/tokens page by filling up the following form
>   https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe9t2VBwje7zO_xMKT3bO92H8nrzsQJCu2KeFU3PLgAjRONLA/viewform
>   , however the ultimate decision will be at our own discretion.

Answer (score 1):

A ERC-20 standard token, is a token that implements at least all the functions listed here:
https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

All the ERC-20 tokens listed, have done at least one Token Transfer Events.

For example, take a look at this ERC-20 token (BAT) : https://etherscan.io/address/0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef#code
it implements all the ERC-20 functions, plus others like refund() and finalize().

A possible solution for testing if is an ERC-20 token could be this: first deploy your token locally, and then try to add it on MEW (you should connect MEW to the local network).

Answer (score 0):

To Verified your ERC-Token and update details you need to contact team of [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/contactus)

[image]